# Is there a way to check hardware whitelist for a laptop?

Tags: laptop, bios, uefi

I have an **Asus n750jv** laptop which has a malfunctioning Wi-Fi module (*Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG*). I'd like to replace it, but it's quite a challenge to find an exact same adapter in my location, and ideally i'd like to find a better alternative. I know that manufactures add so-called hardware whitelist to their laptops, which prevents them from working if some part of hardware does not meet the criteria of this list.

With other manufactures (e.g. HP) it's not a big deal, since they provide this list in publicly available service manuals, but for some reason Asus does not share service manuals for this model (or any other model as it seems).

Is there a way to somehow check this hardware whitelist in my case, without having OEM documentation?

Comment: Are you sure your laptop has a whitelist? Not all of them do.

Comment: @DanielB i don't, but i believe it's better to check this before buying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asus seems only to recommend their own boards at
[Wifi Board Asus n750jv](https://en.accessoires-asus.com/laptop/wifi/board/modele/n750jv):

[image]

So no point in looking to Asus for help.
I suggest buying any WiFi card that has the right dimensions, just assure
that the vendor has a good return policy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know that there are official stores like that. Now i wonder why this Azure Wave adapter costs 25 euro directly from Asus, while you can buy it for 4.5$ on other places..

Comment: Because Asus has the power to ask that much. The card itself might even be the same one that is 4.5$ elsewhere ...

Comment: ... or be the same thingie, but have a slight modification that you cannot tell about - rendering the original 4.5$ module useless without it.

Answer (score -1):

Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 worked for me. Most of the others return "device not found", like the 6205 or 7260.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).